# Calling Java dependency defined in one mule application from another application

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4

I have a mule application where I have added the external jar files as dependencies and invoking java classes. Now I am working on a different application where I need to use the same external jar files as dependency.

Is there a way I could reuse the first application(with java code) in the second one without added the external jars again as dependencies?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should not add the Mule application as a dependency if you only need to use the Jar files for the Java libraries. Just add the dependencies for the Java libraries to the second application.

If you want to reuse the dependency in an onprem Mule deployment you can add it to a common Mule domain.